# Azure KeyVault: How to add Spring properties with hypehen as secrets

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-data

I have below in my `application.properties` file.

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

I have Azure KeyVault. All the properties are saved in this KeyVault. But the problem is, If I add the properties which has  **hyphen** (-), it won't be working as expected.

In KeyVault secret name I am replacing dots with hyphen. When I have hyphens what do I need to do ? Do I need to replace it ?

Comment: Any update for the question? Does it work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the purpose is not to replace dots with hyphens. The question was about how do I handle secrets if they already have hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

As I think, you can create a list and set the application.properties name as the value, when you store them in the key vault, you can set the name with value that replaces the hyphen into dots, when you want to use the application.properties, they are also in the list, you just need to quote the value with the name that replaced the hyphen into dots from the key vault.

The code will like this:

```
variable "list_var" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["spring.jpa.show-sql"]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "test" {
  name = "azureCommonKeyvault"
  resource_group_name = "charles"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "test" {
  name = "${replace(var.list_var[0], ".", "-")}"
  key_vault_id = "${data.azurerm_key_vault.test.id}"
}

output "var_list" {
  value = "${data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.test.value}"
}
```

The output here:

[image]

This is just a possible solution for you. If you need more help or ideas, please let me know.

Comment: This will work for replacing dots with hypehen, is that correct ?? I want to know how do we add application properties having hyphens in it. Because when I add them, it is not working properly.

Comment: @deadbug This is a way that stores the name with dots in the list and stores the values in the key vault. So you can add the application properties with the name in the list and the value in the key vault.

Comment: This is not useful in my case. I have asked the specific situation. What I will do when properties having hyphens. I didn't asked how I can replace dots with hypehen.

Comment: I think you are not getting my point. I know we need to replace dots with hyphen for spring properties. If I have a spring property having both dots and hyphens, it is impossible to add it in KeyVault.

Comment: @deadbug Yes, the key vault cannot store the secret with the name contains dots. So I provide you an indirect way to store them.

Comment: I don't mean to provide an alternate way to replace dots with hyphens, I appreciate your effort. I need to know what we will do if the secret already have hyphen in it ?

Comment: @deadbug If the secret is already added in the key vault and does not have the original name of the property, then you can do nothing.